# Windows Form Application with GMap.NET

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, dictionary, bing-maps

I am trying to use [GMap.NET](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) in WinForm application. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.websofia.com/2013/02/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/) and I place the below code in `Form_Load` event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Initialize map:
  gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingMapProvider.Instance;
  GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
  gmap.SetCurrentPositionByKeywords("Maputo, Mozambique");
}
```

But no map is shown when I run my app, all what is shown is as below image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem and show the map by using the Zoom properties.

```
gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingMapProvider.Instance;
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
gmap.SetCurrentPositionByKeywords("Maputo, Mozambique");
gmap.MinZoom = 1;
gmap.MaxZoom = 17;
gmap.Zoom = 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var _with1 = gmaps;
_with1.Position = new PointLatLng(22.63, 71.58);
_with1.MinZoom = 3;
_with1.MaxZoom = 17;
_with1.Zoom = 8;
_with1.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
_with1.CanDragMap = true;
_with1.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
_with1.DragButton = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left;
_with1.MouseWheelZoomType = GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionAndCenter;
```